# "I have (or) had been studying for my exam since lunchtime and now I am watching TV"

Tags: perfect-continuous

Which sentence is grammatically correct (or maybe both) and why?

1. I have been studying for my exam since lunchtime and now I am watching TV.
   or
2. I had been studying for my exam since lunchtime and now I am watching TV.

The situation is as follows (it's from a student's book):

- Is that the TV I can hear?
- Yes, Dad. I (to study) for my exam since lunchtime, and now I (to watch) TV.

I believe the Present Perfect Continuous has to be used here since I haven't passed the exam and taking a break now.
On the other hand, there is no visible result of my activity, as in "I'm exhausted. I've been studying for an exam", and the speaker has stopped/finished studying.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly is you confusion, can you please edit your question and add more detail? I'm sure you would prefer an answer that explains "why" rather than saying 1 or 2 or neither is correct.

Comment: This sentence is from a textbook (complete the gaps with the verbs in the correct tense).

Comment: And the gap is where you placed "have/had been"? Is the present participle "studying"  in the actual sentence or does the exercise ask you to complete the sentence using the verb "study"?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It should be "hear" -Is that the TV I can hear?

Answer (score 0):

In English we use the **present perfect continuous** for either an action than started sometime in the past and continues to the present or for a *recently* completed action

- ”I **have been studying** since lunchtime…”

the speaker **needs** a break from studying, and changes activity

- “and *now I'm watching* TV”

On the other hand, the **past perfect continuous** is used to express a continued or ongoing action that started in the past and continued sometime in the *past*. The action began in the past, continued in the past and (usually) ended in the past e.g.
“She **had been doing** her homework since lunchtime, and now **needed** a break”